# Writing to a SPI memory

Tags: arduino-nano, spi, memory

Recently I salvaged a BIOS chip (EN25QH16) which has 2 Megabytes of memory (8192 pages, 256 bytes/page). I followed this [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Design-with-Discrete-SPI-Flash-Memory/) and it works. I double checked the opcodes because the code is for a `Winbond` chip, mine is `Eon` and of course, they're the same (standards?). All commands worked as it should. I modified the code that writes `Hello World` string to a page. I tried the command but it returns (from the memory) `Hello Worlb`. This is the snap of the serial monitor:

[image: serialmonitor]
I erased the chip just to make sure and ran the command `test_write` (which I added). It wrote `48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 00 62 03 0b 00 0b 00` which is in ASCII `Hello Worlb` and I don't know why that happened. Btw this is the modified code:

```
/*
    windbond_serial_debug.cpp 
    A simple program for the Arduino IDE to help familiarize you with
    using WinBond flash memory; can also be used to download the entire
    contents of a flash chip to a file via a serial port interface.

    Important bits of the code: the low-level flash functions (which 
    implement the timing diagrams in the datasheet), and a simple 
    serial-port command interface that allows you to talk to your 
    UNO with any generic terminal application (even the command line).

    Copyright 2014, Peter J. Torelli

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>   


Revisions:
    rev 2 - 21-SEP-2014.
    User 'fiaskow' pointed out that driving the WEL instruction after
    program and erase w/o waiting for the op to finish may be corrupting
    execution. Removed this code (also not needed b/c the WEL is already
    cleared after page write or chip erase).
*/

#include <SPI.h>
// SS:   pin 10
// MOSI: pin 11
// MISO: pin 12
// SCK:  pin 13

// WinBond flash commands
#define WB_WRITE_ENABLE       0x06
#define WB_WRITE_DISABLE      0x04
#define WB_CHIP_ERASE         0xc7
#define WB_READ_STATUS_REG_1  0x05
#define WB_READ_DATA          0x03
#define WB_PAGE_PROGRAM       0x02
#define WB_JEDEC_ID           0x9f

/* 
 * These global variables enable assembly of the user serial 
 * input command.
 */
boolean g_command_ready(false);
String g_command;

/*
 * print_page_bytes() is a simple helperf function that formats 256
 * bytes of data into an easier to read grid.
 */
void print_page_bytes(byte *page_buffer) {
  char buf[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
      sprintf(buf, "%02x", page_buffer[i * 16 + j]);
      Serial.print(buf);
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

/*
================================================================================
User Interface Routines
The functions below map to user commands. They wrap the low-level calls with 
print/debug statements for readability.
================================================================================
*/

/* 
 * The JEDEC ID is fairly generic, I use this function to verify the setup
 * is working properly.
 */
void get_jedec_id(void) {
  Serial.println("command: get_jedec_id");
  byte b1, b2, b3;
  _get_jedec_id(&b1, &b2, &b3);
  char buf[128];
  sprintf(buf, "Manufacturer ID: %02xh\nMemory Type: %02xh\nCapacity: %02xh",
    b1, b2, b3);
  Serial.println(buf);
  Serial.println("Ready");
} 

void chip_erase(void) {
  Serial.println("command: chip_erase");
  _chip_erase();
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

void read_page(unsigned int page_number) {
  char buf[80];
  sprintf(buf, "command: read_page(%04xh)", page_number);
  Serial.println(buf);
  byte page_buffer[256];
  _read_page(page_number, page_buffer);
  print_page_bytes(page_buffer);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

void delayed_read_all_pages(void) {
  delay(5000);
  read_all_pages();
  }

void read_all_pages(void) {
  Serial.println("command: read_all_pages");
  byte page_buffer[256];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4096; ++i) {
    _read_page(i, page_buffer);
    print_page_bytes(page_buffer);
  }
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

void write_byte(word page, byte offset, byte databyte) {
  char buf[80];
  sprintf(buf, "command: write_byte(%04xh, %04xh, %02xh)", page, offset, databyte);
  Serial.println(buf);
  byte page_data[256];
  _read_page(page, page_data);
  page_data[offset] = databyte;
  _write_page(page, page_data);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

/*
================================================================================
Low-Level Device Routines
The functions below perform the lowest-level interactions with the flash device.
They match the timing diagrams of the datahsheet. They are called by wrapper 
functions which provide a little more feedback to the user. I made them stand-
alone functions so they can be re-used. Each function corresponds to a flash
instruction opcode.
================================================================================
*/

/*
 * See the timing diagram in section 9.2.35 of the
 * data sheet, "Read JEDEC ID (9Fh)".
 */
void _get_jedec_id(byte *b1, byte *b2, byte *b3) {
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WB_JEDEC_ID);
  *b1 = SPI.transfer(0); // manufacturer id
  *b2 = SPI.transfer(0); // memory type
  *b3 = SPI.transfer(0); // capacity
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  not_busy();
}  

/*
 * See the timing diagram in section 9.2.26 of the
 * data sheet, "Chip Erase (C7h / 06h)". (Note:
 * either opcode works.)
 */
void _chip_erase(void) {
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);  
  SPI.transfer(WB_WRITE_ENABLE);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);  
  SPI.transfer(WB_CHIP_ERASE);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  /* See notes on rev 2 
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);  
  SPI.transfer(WB_WRITE_DISABLE);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  */
  not_busy();
}
void _write_test(void) {
  String sampleText = "Hello World";
  byte data[sampleText.length()];
  sampleText.getBytes(data, sizeof(data));
  _write_page(0,data);
  } 
/*
 * See the timing diagram in section 9.2.10 of the
 * data sheet, "Read Data (03h)".
 */
void _read_page(word page_number, byte *page_buffer) {
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WB_READ_DATA);
  // Construct the 24-bit address from the 16-bit page
  // number and 0x00, since we will read 256 bytes (one
  // page).
  SPI.transfer((page_number >> 8) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >> 0) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    page_buffer[i] = SPI.transfer(0);
  }
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  not_busy();
}

/*
 * See the timing diagram in section 9.2.21 of the
 * data sheet, "Page Program (02h)".
 */
void _write_page(word page_number, byte *page_buffer) {
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);  
  SPI.transfer(WB_WRITE_ENABLE);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);  
  SPI.transfer(WB_PAGE_PROGRAM);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >>  8) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >>  0) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    SPI.transfer(page_buffer[i]);
  }
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  /* See notes on rev 2
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);  
  SPI.transfer(WB_WRITE_DISABLE);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  */
  not_busy();
}

/* 
 * not_busy() polls the status bit of the device until it
 * completes the current operation. Most operations finish
 * in a few hundred microseconds or less, but chip erase 
 * may take 500+ms. Finish all operations with this poll.
 *
 * See section 9.2.8 of the datasheet
 */
void not_busy(void) {
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WB_READ_STATUS_REG_1);       
  while (SPI.transfer(0) & 1) {}; 
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);  
}

/*
 * This handy built-in callback function alerts the UNO
 * whenever a serial event occurs. In our case, we check
 * for available input data and concatenate a command
 * string, setting a boolean used by the loop() routine
 * as a dispatch trigger.
 */
void serialEvent() {
  char c;
  while (Serial.available()) {
    c = (char)Serial.read();
    if (c == ';') {
      g_command_ready = true;
    }
    else {
      g_command += c;
    }    
  }
}

void setup(void) {
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(0);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Ready"); 
}

/*
 * loop() dispatches the commands compiled by the serialEvent
 * parser callback. Some commands take multiple arguments, so
 * I have to split up the strings with some messy manipulation.
 */
void loop(void) {
  if (g_command_ready) {
    if (g_command == "get_jedec_id") {
      get_jedec_id();
    }
    else if (g_command == "test_write") {
      Serial.println("Custom command: test_write");
      _write_test();
      }
    else if (g_command == "chip_erase") {
      chip_erase();
    }
    else if (g_command == "read_all_pages") {
      read_all_pages();
    }
    else if (g_command == "delayed_read_all_pages") {
      Serial.println("Custom command: delayed_read_all_pages");
      delayed_read_all_pages();
      }
    // A one-parameter command...
    else if (g_command.startsWith("read_page")) {
      int pos = g_command.indexOf(" ");
      if (pos == -1) {
        Serial.println("Error: Command 'read_page' expects an int operand");
      } else {
        word page = (word)g_command.substring(pos).toInt();
        read_page(page);
      }
    }
    // A three-parameter command..
    else if (g_command.startsWith("write_byte")) {
      word pageno;
      byte offset;
      byte data;

      String args[3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        int pos = g_command.indexOf(" ");
        if (pos == -1) {
          Serial.println("Syntax error in write_byte");
          goto done;
        }
        args[i] = g_command.substring(pos + 1);
        g_command = args[i];
      }
      pageno = (word)args[0].toInt();
      offset = (byte)args[1].toInt();
      data = (byte)args[2].toInt();
      write_byte(pageno, offset, data);
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Invalid command sent: ");
      Serial.println(g_command);
      g_command = "";
    }
done:
    g_command = "";
    g_command_ready = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `byte data[sampleText.length()];`, should be `byte data[256];`, as _write_page expects the page_buffer to be 256 bytes long. Also `48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 00 62 03 0b 00 0b 00` isn't `Hello Worlb` but `Hello Worl<null>b<etx><vt><null><vt><null>`

Comment: @Gerben `Hello Worlb` is from an online converter but the Notepad++ conversion looks like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C are terminated with a null byte - so the string "A" is in fact two bytes: the 'A' followed by a null.

Your `_write_test()` function counts only the characters in the string, and hence allocates one byte too few.  It should be:

```
void _write_test(void) {
  String sampleText = "Hello World";
  byte data[sampleText.length()+1];
  sampleText.getBytes(data, sizeof(data));
  // See text below before calling write_page()
}
```

But then we hit the issue of how much data `write_page()` will write.  It doesn't have any way of knowing how much data you are passing in - it just gets a pointer.  Looking at its implementation we can see that it writes exactly 256 bytes, so we need to pass in a buffer of 256 bytes.

```
void _write_test(void) {
  String sampleText = "Hello World";
  byte data[256];
  sampleText.getBytes(data, sizeof(data));
  _write_page(0,data);
  }
```

(If we pass in a smaller buffer we're leaving it up to chance what will happen.  The Arduino doesn't have much protection so probably you'll just write garbage, but maybe, just maybe, you'll get unlucky and some weird crash will happen.)

Comment: Yep with my code it writes some garbage (I converted the hex and there's some of it). Well, it works now. Thanks!